# How do I animate my guy jogging on a curve track?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode

I have animated running but only in a straight line I'm trying to make my character jog in an S curve to show off my rig but also figure out how to pose the body especially when the camera is at an awkward angle. My rig has a master bone allowing me to move the entire body but am I supposed to pose the limbs while he's moving how a simple jog becomes so hard? I just need some tips.[image]

Comment: You can animate the whole armature too, if you don't have a root bone, but don't matter. Did you try the Follow Curve constraint?

Comment: I didn't try it what does it do?

Comment: You add a curve object and the desired object will follow it. Its name Follow Path, excuse me. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/path_animation.html

Comment: If you want to watch a quick tutorial [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8jMYuGu_IU) one by Blender Secrets is probably the quickest one but there are many others online.